# Set class if if filled or empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im building my own custom selecter and i need to set a class if something is selected or not. Why is this not working?

Im new to react, so bear with me. I also need to type some more before i can post my question although im not sure how to elaborate this question further since its probably clear to some what im doing wrong.

EDIT: I have changed the props to state, but it is still not working. When i select from the dropdown, i doesn't select the option i choose and also the correct classes aren't set. eg. empty, not-empty, so i think somethings is not correct in the logic?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const optionsData = [
    'Select',
    'Option1',
    'Option2',
    'Option3'
]

class CustomSelect extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            placeholder:'',  
            id:'', 
            onChange:'', 
            label:'', 
            value:'',
            validationMsg:'',
            disabled:''
        };
    }
    onFocus = () => {          
        this.setState({    
            onFocus: true
        });
    }
    // Fix so when you dont make a choice it still lose focus
    onBlur = () => {          
        this.setState({    
            onFocus: false
        });
    }
    onChange = () => {          
        this.setState({    
            onFocus: false
        });
    }    

    getClass = () => {
        if (this.state.onFocus === true)
            return "in-focus"
        else if (!this.state.value === '' | !this.state.value === 'Select')
            return "not-empty"
        else if (this.state.value === '')
            return "empty"
        else
            return "";
    }

    render() {
        let inputFocus = this.getClass();
        return (  
            <div className={`form-item ${inputFocus}`}>
                {this.props.label && 
                    <label htmlFor={this.props.id}>
                        {this.props.label}
                    </label>
                }
                <select 
                    id={this.state.id} 
                    placeholder={this.state.placeholder} 
                    onFocus={this.onFocus}
                    onBlur={this.onBlur}
                    onChange={this.onChange} 
                    disabled={this.state.disabled} 
                    value={this.state.value ? this.props.value : ''}
                > 
                    {optionsData.map(option => 
                        <option 
                            key={option}
                            value={option}
                        >
                            {option}
                        </option>
                    )} 
                </select>
                {/* {this.props.validationMsg && <span className="validation-message">{this.props.validationMsg}</span>} */}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CustomSelect
```

Comment: So what exactly is not working in this? Also, change the name from `setClass ` to `getClass`. That'd b helpful  for others in understanding your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

`this.props.label` to `this.state.label`

`this.props.placeholder` to `this.props.placeholder`

`this.props.id` to `this.state.id`

and similarly for each of those items. Your code should work then.
You might like to go through these:

[State in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

[Props in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Also, change the name of `setClass` to `getClass`. That conveys its usage in a better way.

UPDATE: Now since you're done with the changes, the reason your drop down is not working is because in your `handleChange` you're not setting the state value which you're using in `select`.

```
  onChange = (e) => {          
        this.setState({    
            onFocus: true, <--- you might like to set this true
            value: e.target.value <----- you'll have to do this
        });
    }
```

See this: [See the select section in this](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

Similarly, for other issues you have to set the `state` accordingly.
Also, there were still some `props` needed to be changed to `state`

Here's a working code after these fixes: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-leaf-4h5dp?file=/src/CustomSelect.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'

const optionsData = [
    'Select',
    'Option1',
    'Option2',
    'Option3'
]

class CustomSelect extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            placeholder:'',  
            id:'', 
            onChange:'', 
            label:'', 
            value:'',
            validationMsg:'',
            disabled:''
        };
    }
    onFocus = () => {          
        this.setState({    
            onFocus: true
        });
    }
    // Fix so when you dont make a choice it still lose focus
    onBlur = () => {          
        this.setState({    
            onFocus: false
        });
    }
    onChange = (e) => {          
        this.setState({    
            onFocus: true,
            value: e.target.value
        });
    }    

    getClass = () => {
        if (this.state.onFocus === true)
            return "in-focus"
        else if (!this.state.value === '' | !this.state.value === 'Select')
            return "not-empty"
        else if (this.state.value === '')
            return "empty"
        else
            return "";
    }

    render() {
        let inputFocus = this.getClass();
        return (  
            <div className={`form-item ${inputFocus}`}>
                {this.state.label && 
                    <label htmlFor={this.state.id}>
                        {this.state.label}
                    </label>
                }
                <select 
                    id={this.state.id} 
                    placeholder={this.state.placeholder} 
                    onFocus={this.onFocus}
                    onBlur={this.onBlur}
                    onChange={this.onChange} 
                    disabled={this.state.disabled} 
                    value={this.state.value ? this.state.value : ''}
                > 
                    {optionsData.map(option => 
                        <option 
                            key={option}
                            value={option}
                        >
                            {option}
                        </option>
                    )} 
                </select>
                {/* {this.props.validationMsg && <span className="validation-message">{this.props.validationMsg}</span>} */}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CustomSelect
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have changed the stuff you talked about, but there is still issues. I have updated the main post. Any idea?